# Multiple page form in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, formwizard

I am trying to design a multiple page web form to collect information from the users. Users can quit at any time and then come back later on the page where they left, I send an email to users containing a link back to their application when they start application process. I am wondering if I can do this with asp:wizard? Does anyone know whether I can use asp:wizard to start from a page where user has left along lets assume 3rd page with their filled data and also when they click back, they should be taken to the prev. page i.e. 2nd page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using Wizard anymore, but it is possible to go back to any step of the form wizard by  using Wizard.MoveTo method. [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.moveto.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a good approach. There must be some alternative, that you must try. Nut If this is your requirement, then you might face issues like this

1. You need to maintain a database of the anonymous users or the users that are using the wizard. Result waste of database sapce.
2. How would you define that the returning user is the same genuine user , not some bot or hacker. As this might leads make data public. For example you are Akshay , you filled up to wiz#2 and quit. Now next day you want to complete the form. How the system will know u r Akshay Kumar not Sunil Shetty. Also if some Jhonny Lever come and might take a hit and trial on Akshay , then he will get you.

So take a deep thought on the issue and discuss with the seniors regarding the alternatives, also there are lots of SO Guru, which will definitely suggest you some good way out.

Comment: lol..thanks for explaining it in Bollywood style. There is req. to let users come back again on their application, I use hashing to generate a unique key for each visitor and use it to retrieve values from the table. I am looking for other ways as well.